# display latest post using querybulider through custom repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

i'm following a symfony tutorial & i have managed to display posts from my database, i am now trying
to display latest post but i am getting the following error.

```
Undefined method 'getQueryBuilder'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

my setup is as follows

my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    }
```

my src/Blog/CoreBundle/Controller/PostController

```
namespace Blog\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the post index
     *
     * @return array
     *
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ModelBundle:Post')->findAll();

        $latestPosts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ModelBundle:Post')->findLatest(3);

        return array(
            'posts' => $posts,
            'latestPosts' => $latestPosts
        );
    }

}

my src/Blog/ModelBundle/Entity/Post.php

namespace Blog\ModelBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//adds validator class for validation use
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blog\ModelBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post extends Timestampable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=150)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $body;


    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $author;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }


    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \Blog\ModelBundle\Entity\Author $author
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setAuthor(Author $author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \Blog\ModelBundle\Entity\Author 
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }
}
```

my src/Blog/ModelBundle/Repository/PostRepository.php

```
namespace Blog\ModelBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


/**
 * Class PostRepository
 */
class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{


    /**
     * Find latest
     *
     * @param int $num how many posts to get
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function findLatest($num)
    {
        $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder()
            ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'desc')
            ->setMaxResults($num);

        return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     */
    public function qetQueryBuilder()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $qb = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:Post')
            ->createQueryBuilder('p');

        return $qb;

    }





}
```

my config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

services:
  twig.extension.text:
    class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
    tags:
       - { name: twig.extension }

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

so can anyone suggest to me what i am missing or what steps i'm not taking

Thanks

Comment: Delete all your posted code except for the controller and the PostRepository.  Way too much information.  Put a die statement in findLatest and verify it's being called.  This will verify that you have your Post entity correctly linked to your PostRepository.

Comment: Then get rid of getQueryBuilder and replace with: $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p'); and see where that gets you.

Comment: I just noticed.  Your posted code has qet instead of get.  That is what is causing the error message.  But make the entire method go away.  It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed. apparently it was a typo error

```
public function qetQueryBuilder()
```

should be

```
public function getQueryBuilder()
```